# Trying to calculate the Full Width at Half Minimum of a certain potential

Tags: waves, potential-energy, measurements, mathematics, spectroscopy

I am calculating the Full Width at Half Minimum of several potentials. I came across a potential that has the following form:

[image]

Points a and b are the local maxima of the curve. Point e is the minimum of the potential. If we connect points a and b, we get a straight line drawn in red color. The vertical line passing through point e intersects the red straight line at point f. The half minimum is equal to ef/2. The full width (cd) of the potential is a segment joining two points of the potential curve at half minimum (ef/2). This is similar to the case of Full Width at Half Maximum (FWHM) but instead we have here a minimum and not a maximum.

As we can see, at half minimum, one of the two points (c) lies outside the potential! This means that the full width (cd) doesn't lies inside the potential. I would like to ask whether we can calculate the FWHM in this case or simply not. In other words, do we have such a quantity (FWHM) for this case? Thanks a lot for your suggestions and help.

Comment: As I noted on your previous question: you have a background to subtract off (a baseline correction).

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm afraid that I don't understand what you mean exactly here.

Comment: Perhaps https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31385/baseline-correction-what-is-the-concept-of-a-baseline-shift-and-baseline-correc might be a start. A pretty fundamental concept for spectrum analysis...